# Chick Corea and Return to Forever Romantic Warrior

Tags: jazz

Does Romantic Warrior have a non-instrumental recording?

Each recording online has (instrumental) tagged beside the song title it, so I am not sure if there exists a non-instrumental version.

Answer (score 1):

The song is an instrumental only, although the album was released with a poem called "The Romantic Warrior". Why whomever posted it online chose to include "(instrumental)" is unclear.

Here is an image of the original vinyl album's back cover (best image available). Note there is no mention of "instrumental".

[image: Romantic Warrior vinyl back cover]
(Image source: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUUtJmWsvh8))

The US Library of Congress lists [16 items](https://cocatalog.loc.gov/cgi-bin/Pwebrecon.cgi?PostSearchSortBy1=PUB_DATE&HID=20818082&HID=12771048&HID=10931816&HID=7786078&HID=1259365&HID=23578195&HID=3058069&HID=8862106&HID=25157069&HID=12194948&HID=9161321&HID=9212005&HID=9240137&HID=33393531&HID=27132790&HID=6207387&PostSearchSortBy2=NULL&Search_Arg=Romantic%20warrior.&Search_Code=TALL&ti=1%2C0&CNT=25&PID=OrGeGLrXpv1aTym8bvwZXtEksJf1X&SEQ=20230331182557&REC=0&RD=0&RC=0&MAILADDY=&EMAILADDRESS=None&LIMITBUTTON=0) titled "(The) Romantic Warrior". Of the items that are music (there are some non-musical items with the same title), there is one, attributed to Igor Kissil (music) and Alan Cohen (lyrics) that would seem to include vocals, but I haven't been able to track down the actual recording, and it would seem to be an entirely different tune — based on the fact that Kissil is listed as the composer.

[image: Library of Congress listings]